# Angular regex: To allow only mid letter spaces and remove starting/ending white space

Tags: regex, typescript, angular6

i am stuck at a problem in Angular and i am using primeNg.
I want to stop user from entering empty white spaces to the input filed but should allow space in between

```
<input type="text" pInputText class="input-field" formControlName="relation" />
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
^[^\s](.*[^\s])?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/IjBiIC/1/

Comment: @juhi I did, it's at the end of my answer.

Comment: Its doesn't allow in word spaces

Comment: <input type="text" [pKeyFilter]="test" pInputText class="input-field address" formControlName="address" />


test: RegExp = /^[^\s](.*[^\s])?$/;

Comment: @juhi It sounds like your app is applying this regex after every keystroke. You need to change your app logic to not perform so mindlessly.